# Use JavaScript library chessboard.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, chessboard.js

I'm not very familiar with JavaScript.
I want to use the chessboard.js library, but the rendered chessboard does not display the pieces (just the board).
I did exactly the same thing as recommended here: [How do I use chessboard.js , a javascript chessboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38927285/how-do-i-use-chessboard-js-a-javascript-chessboard)

My code looks like:

```
   <html>
<head>
    <title>Test chessboard.js</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="chessboardjs-1.0.0/css/chessboard-1.0.0.css">

</head>
<body>

    <div id="myBoard" style="width: 400px"></div>

    <script src="jquery-3.6.3/jquery-3.6.3.js"></script>
    <script src="chessboardjs-1.0.0/js/chessboard-1.0.0.js"></script>
    <script>
        var ruyLopez = 'r1bqkbnr/pppp1ppp/2n5/1B2p3/4P3/5N2/PPPP1PPP/RNBQK2R'
        var board = Chessboard('myBoard', ruyLopez)
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Works fine for me with CDN links. Can you share a [mcve]? Do you have the images downloaded? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You needs to copy chess pieces in your local.

From

```
https://github.com/oakmac/chessboardjs/tree/master/website/img/chesspieces/wikipedia
```

To your local

[image]

Then this example HTML can see the peases
Due to all pieces **img** `src` linked related location

Example

```
<img src="img/chesspieces/wikipedia/bR.png" ...>
```

Start Example HTML

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>chessboardjs Example #1001 - Start Position</title>
    <base href="../">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@chrisoakman/chessboardjs@1.0.0/dist/chessboard-1.0.0.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-q94+BZtLrkL1/ohfjR8c6L+A6qzNH9R2hBLwyoAfu3i/WCvQjzL2RQJ3uNHDISdU" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <p><a href="examples#1001">← Back to all examples.</a></p>

    <p>Pass <code class="js string">'start'</code> as the second argument to initialize
        the board to the start position.</p>

    <!--- Begin Example HTML ------------------------------------------------------>
    <div id="myBoard" style="width: 400px">
        <div class="chessboard-63f37">
            <div class="board-b72b1" style="width: 392px;">
                <div class="row-5277c">
                    <div class="square-55d63 white-1e1d7 square-a8" style="width:49px;height:49px;"
                        id="a8-f17f-9aeb-5964-f762-85c0-fae2-2903-ba25" data-square="a8">
                        <div class="notation-322f9 numeric-fc462">8</div><img src="img/chesspieces/wikipedia/bR.png"
                            alt="" class="piece-417db" data-piece="bR" style="width:49px;height:49px;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="square-55d63 black-3c85d square-b8" style="width:49px;height:49px;"
                        id="b8-95aa-e5f7-b84b-c146-4596-074f-4990-85b4" data-square="b8"><img
                            src="img/chesspieces/wikipedia/bN.png" alt="" class="piece-417db" data-piece="bN"
                            style="width:49px;height:49px;"></div>
                    <div class="square-55d63 white-1e1d7 square-c8" style="width:49px;height:49px;"
                        id="c8-16a2-bb23-6559-a81d-0fd5-727e-8a09-55af" data-square="c8"><img
                            src="img/chesspieces/wikipedia/bB.png" alt="" class="piece-417db" data-piece="bB"
                            style="width:49px;height:49px;"></div>
                    <div class="square-55d63 black-3c85d square-d8" style="width:49px;height:49px;"
                        id="d8-c09a-87d5-7752-4037-3000-fbfe-3d79-cc18" data-square="d8"><img
                            src="img/chesspieces/wikipedia/bQ.png" alt="" class="piece-417db" data-piece="bQ"
                            style="width:49px;height:49px;"></div>
                    <div class="square-55d63 white-1e1d7 square-e8" style="width:49px;height:49px;"
                        id="e8-6b8f-caa7-1219-be3f-3229-caba-aade-3d48" data-square="e8"><img
                            src="img/chesspieces/wikipedia/bK.png" alt="" class="piece-417db" data-piece="bK"
                            style="width:49px;height:49px;"></div>
                    <div class="square-55d63 black-3c85d square-f8" style="width:49px;height:49px;"
                        id="f8-f713-7c33-8aec-b40f-2fc4-8804-a71c-a355" data-square="f8"><img
                            src="img/chesspieces/wikipedia/bB.png" alt="" class="piece-417db" data-piece="bB"
                            style="width:49px;height:49px;"></div>
                    <div class="square-55d63 white-1e1d7 square-g8" style="width:49px;height:49px;"
                        id="g8-05b2-bd42-4b46-aa98-572f-feb9-4daa-840f" data-square="g8"><img
                            src="img/chesspieces/wikipedia/bN.png" alt="" class="piece-417db" data-piece="bN"
                            style="width:49px;height:49px;"></div>
                    <div class="square-55d63 black-3c85d square-h8" style="width:49px;height:49px;"
                        id="h8-5529-71b3-8f39-71e3-88ee-73ce-8724-7078" data-square="h8"><img
                            src="img/chesspieces/wikipedia/bR.png" alt="" class="piece-417db" data-piece="bR"
                            style="width:49px;height:49px;"></div>
                    <div class="clearfix-7da63"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row-5277c">
                    <div class="square-55d63 black-3c85d square-a7" style="width:49px;height:49px;"
                        id="a7-2e8d-87d0-3d94-dec5-1ba9-c2fa-5722-597d" data-square="a7">
                        <div class="notation-322f9 numeric-fc462">7</div><img src="img/chesspieces/wikipedia/bP.png"
                            alt="" class="piece-417db" data-piece="bP" style="width:49px;height:49px;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="square-55d63 white-1e1d7 square-b7" style="width:49px;height:49px;"
                        id="b7-b55c-086c-4728-74ce-68ce-5b4d-9f5f-e83f" data-square="b7"><img
                            src="img/chesspieces/wikipedia/bP.png" alt="" class="piece-417db" data-piece="bP"
                            style="width:49px;height:49px;"></div>
                    <div class="square-55d63 black-3c85d square-c7" style="width:49px;height:49px;"
                        id="c7-9745-74de-330c-3612-69e4-d973-d097-7c1f" data-square="c7"><img
                            src="img/chesspieces/wikipedia/bP.png" alt="" class="piece-417db" data-piece="bP"
                            style="width:49px;height:49px;"></div>
                    <div class="square-55d63 white-1e1d7 square-d7" style="width:49px;height:49px;"
                        id="d7-feb5-fda2-f296-dc23-2d4a-dfb9-d59a-7abe" data-square="d7"><img
                            src="img/chesspieces/wikipedia/bP.png" alt="" class="piece-417db" data-piece="bP"
                            style="width:49px;height:49px;"></div>
                    <div class="square-55d63 black-3c85d square-e7" style="width:49px;height:49px;"
                        id="e7-8b01-88a8-abde-8a89-8ffc-b634-d374-c480" data-square="e7"><img
                            src="img/chesspieces/wikipedia/bP.png" alt="" class="piece-417db" data-piece="bP"
                            style="width:49px;height:49px;"></div>
                    <div class="square-55d63 white-1e1d7 square-f7" style="width:49px;height:49px;"
                        id="f7-1c8c-6e2a-1af9-6813-3ea4-69b4-173f-10c9" data-square="f7"><img
                            src="img/chesspieces/wikipedia/bP.png" alt="" class="piece-417db" data-piece="bP"
                            style="width:49px;height:49px;"></div>
                    <div class="square-55d63 black-3c85d square-g7" style="width:49px;height:49px;"
                        id="g7-91ea-b572-f651-b134-2fc9-dd91-9bdf-307c" data-square="g7"><img
                            src="img/chesspieces/wikipedia/bP.png" alt="" class="piece-417db" data-piece="bP"
                            style="width:49px;height:49px;"></div>
                    <div class="square-55d63 white-1e1d7 square-h7" style="width:49px;height:49px;"
                        id="h7-4666-349e-fafb-eeaa-6324-f265-a678-464a" data-square="h7"><img
                            src="img/chesspieces/wikipedia/bP.png" alt="" class="piece-417db" data-piece="bP"
                            style="width:49px;height:49px;"></div>
                    <div class="clearfix-7da63"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row-5277c">
                    <div class="square-55d63 white-1e1d7 square-a6" style="width:49px;height:49px;"
                        id="a6-98d1-7b76-7fd8-1da0-c5b3-1490-b8cb-dda9" data-square="a6">
                        <div class="notation-322f9 numeric-fc462">6</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="square-55d63 black-3c85d square-b6" style="width:49px;height:49px;"
                        id="b6-8931-e25b-881d-c7ce-142a-f1d1-f915-c2b2" data-square="b6"></div>
                    <div class="square-55d63 white-1e1d7 square-c6" style="width:49px;height:49px;"
                        id="c6-7730-5a43-be81-1c6e-6ecb-d57f-bed0-db46" data-square="c6"></div>
                    <div class="square-55d63 black-3c85d square-d6" style="width:49px;height:49px;"
                        id="d6-325e-bfdf-4832-7c5b-e30f-9909-68f0-a909" data-square="d6"></div>
                    <div class="square-55d63 white-1e1d7 square-e6" style="width:49px;height:49px;"
                        id="e6-9e67-444c-0ba3-a651-73e0-396c-41bf-a1ce" data-square="e6"></div>
                    <div class="square-55d63 black-3c85d square-f6" style="width:49px;height:49px;"
                        id="f6-91b4-4aed-d85e-067b-1f40-f1e4-dfdc-7bce" data-square="f6"></div>
                    <div class="square-55d63 white-1e1d7 square-g6" style="width:49px;height:49px;"
                        id="g6-3398-7ff5-4ae5-510a-cb40-c24e-1ae8-b668" data-square="g6"></div>
                    <div class="square-55d63 black-3c85d square-h6" style="width:49px;height:49px;"
                        id="h6-241e-322a-b387-9975-0c24-5d5f-3ee6-e506" data-square="h6"></div>
                    <div class="clearfix-7da63"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row-5277c">
                    <div class="square-55d63 black-3c85d square-a5" style="width:49px;height:49px;"
                        id="a5-c057-6d39-8b0d-f919-ab68-0a1a-2162-e90a" data-square="a5">
                        <div class="notation-322f9 numeric-fc462">5</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="square-55d63 white-1e1d7 square-b5" style="width:49px;height:49px;"
                        id="b5-130f-c473-a614-de49-8a8c-62ce-00ee-1e8d" data-square="b5"></div>
                    <div class="square-55d63 black-3c85d square-c5" style="width:49px;height:49px;"
                        id="c5-f302-e133-886a-ec0b-3796-a3f1-ce6c-7f7b" data-square="c5"></div>
                    <div class="square-55d63 white-1e1d7 square-d5" style="width:49px;height:49px;"
                        id="d5-1f4f-339c-387f-1496-ce7e-5592-a67b-3fc0" data-square="d5"></div>
                    <div class="square-55d63 black-3c85d square-e5" style="width:49px;height:49px;"
                        id="e5-3f2b-fc0c-2ff8-cc5f-fa96-d320-731e-3d4e" data-square="e5"></div>
                    <div class="square-55d63 white-1e1d7 square-f5" style="width:49px;height:49px;"
                        id="f5-b162-087c-ee97-7e8a-e217-f92c-e925-28cf" data-square="f5"></div>
                    <div class="square-55d63 black-3c85d square-g5" style="width:49px;height:49px;"
                        id="g5-4656-df38-97b9-f9b9-3d2c-caec-f32b-13e5" data-square="g5"></div>
                    <div class="square-55d63 white-1e1d7 square-h5" style="width:49px;height:49px;"
                        id="h5-d353-8199-90bb-fd45-e034-7b1a-64d4-a8ba" data-square="h5"></div>
                    <div class="clearfix-7da63"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row-5277c">
                    <div class="square-55d63 white-1e1d7 square-a4" style="width:49px;height:49px;"
                        id="a4-9207-7ff8-c0f2-3078-1522-8ce4-0442-086e" data-square="a4">
                        <div class="notation-322f9 numeric-fc462">4</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="square-55d63 black-3c85d square-b4" style="width:49px;height:49px;"
                        id="b4-c31b-c51f-1254-810a-57cd-0090-d13b-c2f3" data-square="b4"></div>
                    <div class="square-55d63 white-1e1d7 square-c4" style="width:49px;height:49px;"
                        id="c4-d435-f8b2-7719-0784-63a6-21c0-a412-8581" data-square="c4"></div>
                    <div class="square-55d63 black-3c85d square-d4" style="width:49px;height:49px;"
                        id="d4-85cb-f4e6-0b14-78f0-5f2c-a677-a525-d8f1" data-square="d4"></div>
                    <div class="square-55d63 white-1e1d7 square-e4" style="width:49px;height:49px;"
                        id="e4-ac1f-04d1-d992-7648-d5da-c389-43a7-9a2d" data-square="e4"></div>
                    <div class="square-55d63 black-3c85d square-f4" style="width:49px;height:49px;"
                        id="f4-f72b-9b6e-008d-1e1c-2e2f-8174-64d4-fdd9" data-square="f4"></div>
                    <div class="square-55d63 white-1e1d7 square-g4" style="width:49px;height:49px;"
                        id="g4-7b8a-0680-1ec3-0c97-224f-3ced-3eb4-ff9f" data-square="g4"></div>
                    <div class="square-55d63 black-3c85d square-h4" style="width:49px;height:49px;"
                        id="h4-cd7b-cbfc-8f0e-ee8e-2cf2-d3d1-f091-5091" data-square="h4"></div>
                    <div class="clearfix-7da63"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row-5277c">
                    <div class="square-55d63 black-3c85d square-a3" style="width:49px;height:49px;"
                        id="a3-b168-e2d7-4bef-91f6-edd4-edd5-c96d-5b0d" data-square="a3">
                        <div class="notation-322f9 numeric-fc462">3</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="square-55d63 white-1e1d7 square-b3" style="width:49px;height:49px;"
                        id="b3-b760-8b44-e005-b8bf-4f81-9cf6-98de-1d2a" data-square="b3"></div>
                    <div class="square-55d63 black-3c85d square-c3" style="width:49px;height:49px;"
                        id="c3-e641-b444-0668-ab45-b6bb-3c23-a588-e7d7" data-square="c3"></div>
                    <div class="square-55d63 white-1e1d7 square-d3" style="width:49px;height:49px;"
                        id="d3-22d6-563f-20df-2a77-97e5-eb45-0db3-310b" data-square="d3"></div>
                    <div class="square-55d63 black-3c85d square-e3" style="width:49px;height:49px;"
                        id="e3-035f-7cd1-e585-814e-6052-d8d2-46ee-938d" data-square="e3"></div>
                    <div class="square-55d63 white-1e1d7 square-f3" style="width:49px;height:49px;"
                        id="f3-cda6-2082-72be-459b-11a1-a2a6-84d4-a959" data-square="f3"></div>
                    <div class="square-55d63 black-3c85d square-g3" style="width:49px;height:49px;"
                        id="g3-f79a-603e-8068-2bf2-020b-c817-23b6-c533" data-square="g3"></div>
                    <div class="square-55d63 white-1e1d7 square-h3" style="width:49px;height:49px;"
                        id="h3-bd55-5b89-064f-9b98-9268-3c77-f7ff-f9f6" data-square="h3"></div>
                    <div class="clearfix-7da63"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row-5277c">
                    <div class="square-55d63 white-1e1d7 square-a2" style="width:49px;height:49px;"
                        id="a2-3f23-f06f-0c86-d153-9b4f-0552-d729-f8ef" data-square="a2">
                        <div class="notation-322f9 numeric-fc462">2</div><img src="img/chesspieces/wikipedia/wP.png"
                            alt="" class="piece-417db" data-piece="wP" style="width:49px;height:49px;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="square-55d63 black-3c85d square-b2" style="width:49px;height:49px;"
                        id="b2-7c0a-2811-f662-3715-9966-cae9-5ffa-5afe" data-square="b2"><img
                            src="img/chesspieces/wikipedia/wP.png" alt="" class="piece-417db" data-piece="wP"
                            style="width:49px;height:49px;"></div>
                    <div class="square-55d63 white-1e1d7 square-c2" style="width:49px;height:49px;"
                        id="c2-710d-3f5f-1244-3859-4e91-d33f-dd6f-1a10" data-square="c2"><img
                            src="img/chesspieces/wikipedia/wP.png" alt="" class="piece-417db" data-piece="wP"
                            style="width:49px;height:49px;"></div>
                    <div class="square-55d63 black-3c85d square-d2" style="width:49px;height:49px;"
                        id="d2-7d42-de3d-bf75-881d-d91a-8e2f-2246-c481" data-square="d2"><img
                            src="img/chesspieces/wikipedia/wP.png" alt="" class="piece-417db" data-piece="wP"
                            style="width:49px;height:49px;"></div>
                    <div class="square-55d63 white-1e1d7 square-e2" style="width:49px;height:49px;"
                        id="e2-482d-a6ee-785c-ba9d-800e-673f-da55-e2b6" data-square="e2"><img
                            src="img/chesspieces/wikipedia/wP.png" alt="" class="piece-417db" data-piece="wP"
                            style="width:49px;height:49px;"></div>
                    <div class="square-55d63 black-3c85d square-f2" style="width:49px;height:49px;"
                        id="f2-fd12-1d3f-0cc0-f18a-8bfb-071a-15aa-c7ca" data-square="f2"><img
                            src="img/chesspieces/wikipedia/wP.png" alt="" class="piece-417db" data-piece="wP"
                            style="width:49px;height:49px;"></div>
                    <div class="square-55d63 white-1e1d7 square-g2" style="width:49px;height:49px;"
                        id="g2-76ba-e7fb-2ec6-9089-e8bd-d238-bdea-10b4" data-square="g2"><img
                            src="img/chesspieces/wikipedia/wP.png" alt="" class="piece-417db" data-piece="wP"
                            style="width:49px;height:49px;"></div>
                    <div class="square-55d63 black-3c85d square-h2" style="width:49px;height:49px;"
                        id="h2-213c-b80f-7d97-70ff-99e8-f7f7-ac64-0a52" data-square="h2"><img
                            src="img/chesspieces/wikipedia/wP.png" alt="" class="piece-417db" data-piece="wP"
                            style="width:49px;height:49px;"></div>
                    <div class="clearfix-7da63"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row-5277c">
                    <div class="square-55d63 black-3c85d square-a1" style="width:49px;height:49px;"
                        id="a1-b6a0-9b71-f3aa-3df2-e12c-3d2a-368d-9fdf" data-square="a1">
                        <div class="notation-322f9 alpha-d2270">a</div>
                        <div class="notation-322f9 numeric-fc462">1</div><img src="img/chesspieces/wikipedia/wR.png"
                            alt="" class="piece-417db" data-piece="wR" style="width:49px;height:49px;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="square-55d63 white-1e1d7 square-b1" style="width:49px;height:49px;"
                        id="b1-2887-a216-6684-a69b-5395-8b0a-a8d5-7c60" data-square="b1">
                        <div class="notation-322f9 alpha-d2270">b</div><img src="img/chesspieces/wikipedia/wN.png"
                            alt="" class="piece-417db" data-piece="wN" style="width:49px;height:49px;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="square-55d63 black-3c85d square-c1" style="width:49px;height:49px;"
                        id="c1-0154-ae3b-4d89-cf6b-7b6f-013c-8d40-a286" data-square="c1">
                        <div class="notation-322f9 alpha-d2270">c</div><img src="img/chesspieces/wikipedia/wB.png"
                            alt="" class="piece-417db" data-piece="wB" style="width:49px;height:49px;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="square-55d63 white-1e1d7 square-d1" style="width:49px;height:49px;"
                        id="d1-4662-e4f0-d649-1092-f9a5-df06-d7c9-ac9e" data-square="d1">
                        <div class="notation-322f9 alpha-d2270">d</div><img src="img/chesspieces/wikipedia/wQ.png"
                            alt="" class="piece-417db" data-piece="wQ" style="width:49px;height:49px;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="square-55d63 black-3c85d square-e1" style="width:49px;height:49px;"
                        id="e1-4bd7-3fdd-cc9d-40a6-6333-23f3-a788-c62e" data-square="e1">
                        <div class="notation-322f9 alpha-d2270">e</div><img src="img/chesspieces/wikipedia/wK.png"
                            alt="" class="piece-417db" data-piece="wK" style="width:49px;height:49px;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="square-55d63 white-1e1d7 square-f1" style="width:49px;height:49px;"
                        id="f1-a0ad-e5e3-86ca-fcb8-50c5-9177-1fe0-6198" data-square="f1">
                        <div class="notation-322f9 alpha-d2270">f</div><img src="img/chesspieces/wikipedia/wB.png"
                            alt="" class="piece-417db" data-piece="wB" style="width:49px;height:49px;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="square-55d63 black-3c85d square-g1" style="width:49px;height:49px;"
                        id="g1-56cb-b246-672c-6599-8c75-549e-6438-e3c3" data-square="g1">
                        <div class="notation-322f9 alpha-d2270">g</div><img src="img/chesspieces/wikipedia/wN.png"
                            alt="" class="piece-417db" data-piece="wN" style="width:49px;height:49px;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="square-55d63 white-1e1d7 square-h1" style="width:49px;height:49px;"
                        id="h1-2268-d987-6476-4b5a-acd3-eb2a-7445-e1fa" data-square="h1">
                        <div class="notation-322f9 alpha-d2270">h</div><img src="img/chesspieces/wikipedia/wR.png"
                            alt="" class="piece-417db" data-piece="wR" style="width:49px;height:49px;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix-7da63"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--- End Example HTML -------------------------------------------------------->

    <script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@chrisoakman/chessboardjs@1.0.0/dist/chessboard-1.0.0.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-8Vi8VHwn3vjQ9eUHUxex3JSN/NFqUg3QbPyX8kWyb93+8AC/pPWTzj+nHtbC5bxD"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        // --- Begin Example JS --------------------------------------------------------
        var board = Chessboard('myBoard', 'start')
  // --- End Example JS ----------------------------------------------------------
    </script><img src="img/chesspieces/wikipedia/wP.png" id="a6b0-7a4e-2826-6b82-67d1-183e-90f3-ea2a" alt=""
        class="piece-417db" data-piece="wP" style="width: 49px; height: 49px; display: none;">


</body>

</html>
```

I running with [Live Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) which HTML local server extension in VS code.

[image]

You can find all of example in
[here](https://chessboardjs.com/examples#1001)

[here](https://github.com/oakmac/chessboardjs/tree/master/examples)

[here](https://github.com/shaack/cm-chessboard)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem finally.
I had to move my index.html with the code posted in the question to the folder chessboardjs-1.0.0
Then I also needed to update the paths in my index.html like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/chessboard-1.0.0.css">
<script src="jquery-3.6.3/jquery-3.6.3.js"></script>
<script src="js/chessboard-1.0.0.js"></script>
```

Or keep everything the way it was and change in chessboard-1.0.0.js the line

```
config.pieceTheme = 'img/chesspieces/wikipedia/{piece}.png';
```

to

```
config.pieceTheme = 'chessboardjs-1.0.0/img/chesspieces/wikipedia/{piece}.png';
```

I find it strange however, that the .js file doesn't interpret the relative paths relative to its own location.